# electronjs always refresh after clicking a button

Tags: electron

I am using electron in building Desktop application when I am clicking on any button it make refresh for the whole application  , I need to prevent this refresh

```
  <script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery')
    $(function(){
    var config = require('../jsonFiles/pathData.json');
    $("#aspnetCorePathRename").val(config.AspnetCorePath);
    $("#angularPathRename").val(config.AngularPath);
    });
    function ren(e) {
        const fs = require("fs");
        fs.readFile('./scrips/Rename.ps1', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {

            $(".Console").html(err.toString());
            alert(err.toString());
            return console.error(err);

        }
        alert(data.toString());
        });
        readFile();

  

    }

    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

That's most likely not a Problem of electron or your Script, but of the way you defined the buttons in your HTML. If you define it like this:

`<input type="submit">`

HTML assumes it's send button for a form and will refresh the page. If you define it as button

`<button type='button'>Submit</button>`

the page will not be refreshed.

If you have to define it as input I'd assume you prevent the default behaviour with jQuery like this:

`$("input[type='submit']").click(function() { return false; });`

Comment: My Button defined like below in HTML
<div class="text-center">
                        <button id="btnRename" onClick="ren()" class="btn btn-info" >Rename</button>
                    </div>

Comment: Oh. In this case the HTML seems correct (except it should be `onclick ` not `onClick` ). You could try to set ` event.preventDefault()` to the button to see if it is your script or some default behaviour that triggers the reload.

Comment: This `event.preventDefault()` helped. Even when this button wasn't a submit button and it did a completely different thing.